# Добрый день! Пишу бота для Telegram на Python. Использую модуль webbrowser для создания e-mail письма. Ссылка открывается не на том устройстве

Tags: python, telebot, email, webbrowser

Есть вот такая часть кода:

```
# Создаем функцию для формирования письма на почту магазина и открытия его в почтовом клиенте
def send_email(director_id):
  global director_data # используем глобальную переменную
  director = director_data[str(director_id)] # получаем данные директора по его id
  user_id = director['user_id'] # получаем id пользователя
  from_store = director['from_store'] # получаем название магазина из которого перемещаем
  to_store = director['to_store'] # получаем название магазина куда перемещаем
  items = director['items'] # получаем список позиций и их количество
  director_email = director['director_email'] # получаем адрес e-mail магазина
  
  # создаем пустую строку
  body_text = ''
  # добавляем приветствие и информацию о перемещении
  body_text += f'Здравствуйте! Пользователь с номером {user_id} хочет сделать перемещение из магазина {from_store} в магазин {to_store}. Вот список позиций и их количество:\n'
  # добавляем каждую позицию и ее количество
  for item in items: # для каждой позиции
    body_text += f'{item[0]} - {item[1]}\n' # добавляем название и количество в тело письма
  # добавляем информацию о согласовании
  body_text += 'Этот запрос был согласован директором дивизиона.'

  # Формируем URL-адрес для создания письма в почтовом клиенте с кодировкой русских букв
  subject = f'Перемещение из бутика {from_store} в бутик {to_store} от {datetime.date.today().strftime("%d %B %Y")}'
  subject = urllib.parse.quote(subject)
  body_text = urllib.parse.quote(body_text)
  
  url = f"mailto:{director_email}?subject={subject}&body={body_text}"

  # Открываем URL-адрес в браузере по умолчанию
  webbrowser.open(url)
```

Проблема в том, что запускаю бота на iphone, а итоговое письмо почему-то создается на MacBook. Полагаю, происходит из-за синхронизации настроек между браузерами ( на обоих устройствах по умолчанию браузер Safari).

Как по итогу заставить все-таки ссылку открываться на устройстве, на котором идет работа с ботом?

Использовать другие модули для создания почты не могу по ряду обстоятельств, вынужден пользоваться именно webbrowser.

Comment: Генерация письма осуществляется на устройстве, на котором вы запускаете свой скрипт. И это МакБук. Телеграм бот не выполняется на стороне клиента(на Айфоне). Он просто отправляет сообщения в телеграм. А бот в свою очередь опрашивает сервер телеграма об обновлениях, обрабатывает их и отправляет ответ(через сервер телеграма) на клиентское приложение

Comment: Понятно, спасибо.
Тогда одним из возможных решений будет не генерация письма из webbrowser.open, а например создание сообщения ссылкой, при нажатие на которую будет происходить генерация письма и переход в почтовый клиент пользователя.
Криво, но по идее должно помочь.

Comment: Да @Alexander, именно так.

Comment: Михаил, благодарю!
Сделал вывод сообщения со ссылкой, работает но выглядит по-спартански)
Решил сделать кнопку со ссылкой и столкнулся с проблемой - если использовать InlineKeyboardButton с атрибутом url, то к началу ссылки принудительно добавляется "http://", что делает ссылку mailto бессмысленной и нерабочей.
Как бы обойти добавление "http://" в начало ссылки?